# What is the overall complexity of several algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

The time of extract min=O(logn)

bubble-sort=O(n)

Breath-first-search=O(n+E)

For example, if an algorithm runs in O(logn) + O(n) + O(n+E) or O(logn + n + E)(I'm confused), can I say that's an O(logn) overall time complexity of above algorithms?

What is correct?

Comment: I assume E is the number of edges in a graph? Can you give a better explanation?

Comment: @Rup I agree. It's either O(n), O(E) or O(n+E). Depend on E.

Comment: Bubble Sort complexity is O(n^2).

Answer (score 2):

The Big-O notation shows how (approximately) the runtime would grow when the size of the input grows. When adding complexities, you take the "worst" of them all. O(log(n)) is negligible compared to O(n+E), as is O(n). So, if you have an algorithm that combines all these parts, the overall complexity would be O(n + E).

Comment: Not exactly, it depends on how big is E. If ```E >> n``` then it's O(E), If ```E ~ n``` it's O(E+n) and if ```E << n``` it's O(n).

Comment: @Ohad true 'dat, but note that the original part of the problem was already defined as O(n+E), and the same logic should be applied already there.